# Design considerations for OAuth2 secured APIs

Tags: api, identityserver3, openid-connect, oauth-2.0

I'll give a scenario as a premise for my question:

- CRM client app
- Customers API
- IDP protecting the API
- Customers api required scope : "customers"
- CRM client app OAuth2 client has "customers" scope access granted
- CRM client app requests tokens with scope "customers" and uses the API with the tokens

At some point, developers decide it is time to refactor invoicing out of customers API into a new Invoices API which now requires the scope "invoices". For the Customers API to return expected results to the CRM client app, it will now have to call on Invoices API and get that part of information out to the calling app. So passing on the token won't work because of the new scope requirement.

What is the best approach for the Customers API to keep returning the expected results to the CRM app without breaking change of requiring the CRM client app to add new scopes?

One approach would be for Customers API to authenticate as client credentials trusted subsystem but how will then Invoices API know about the initiating user? The idea here is to separate the functionality without breaking it for existing client applications.

Answer (score 2):

Using a multi-hop or act-as granting system could help you. If I understood correctly your scenario is: `Client -> API1 -> API2`

If you  want each layer to have his own scope (you do according to your description) then `act-as tokens` will help you.

A very good summary of this is available in [IdentityServer samples issue #182](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/issues/182). You'll find an example of that scenario in [their Git repository](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Multi%20Hop%20Delegation%20(ActAsCustomGrant)).

Comment: You understood correctly. However, what happens then if API1 receives a request from another client with client credentials flow, meaning there is no subject in the token? The ActAs validation would not cover for that scenario.